# javascript events and callback

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, function

I am working on a website, where we want user to login using Javascript and not using 
postback. I have few pages which user can view without logging in, but on these pages
if he wants to do something like "Add to favourite" or "Report abuse" or similar, he has to log in. I can display a div where he can log in. But I want the system to perform the task
he initially tried to do. So say if the user wants to perform "Add to favourite", he should first log in and on success othere function "Add to favourite" should be called. So logic
should know where to delegate once user is logged in.

As this loging stuff is required for many other purposes too, so I can hard code one function once log on is successful. I need something like delegation which Login Routine
should know so that it calls it back.

Help will be appritiated.

Regards
Parminder

Comment: Logging in without a postback to the server is highly insecure. It can be bypassed in no time. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: What is your website backend?  Are you trying to accomplish this using JavaScript alone?  PHP, ASP?  What database is storing your user information?

Comment: @TenaciousImpy - That would depend on your authentication implementation. If login returns a session ID, though the user may be able to hack the page to make the UI (client-side) let him submit the actions, if the server requires that session ID in the next call to complete the action, the error would be thrown at that point, keeping the site secure.

Comment: @Renesis - That's true, but the returning of a session ID would require a postback. If no postback is supposed to occur in this authentication method, it's implied that the password is being checked client-side.

Comment: @TenaciousImpy - I assumed the OP was using "Postback" to mean letting the browser submit the form the normal way... I assumed AJAX as an alternative.  You are correct that if you have *NO* server interaction, you certainly cannot have a secure system.

Comment: @Renesis - Ah yes, fair enough. I just read it as a simple JS check to authenticate. If it's just not a full-page postback (which makes more sense), then your session ID method would work just fine.

Comment: @TenaciousImpy I am using SQL Server/asp.net for my site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes you have some basic experience with AJAX and callbacks...

```
// When the user submits the login form, call the login function with
// the original call as the third parameter

function login(username, password, callback) {
    // Perform AJAX call with username and password.
    // Your AJAX utility should call loginResult as its callback
    // Store the callback parameter on your object somewhere
}

function loginResult(result, callback) {
    if (/* Check if the result contains a valid user or sessionID, etc. */) {
         // Logged in, yay.  Do stuff to the UI to show this.
         if (callback) callback();
    } else {
         // Error logging in, oh no.  Display error.
    }
}
```

Comment: this login function is being called on the button click on the login screen, how this function will know what is callback function.

Comment: @parminder - a number of ways; you could store it on the form object that represents your login form.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the `lastAttemptedAction` in the session, and always check this upon a successful login. So the order of events would be:

1. User accesses site anonymously
2. User clicks "add to favorite"
3. "Add to favorite" is added to `Session.lastAttemptedAction`
4. User is asked to login
5. User successfully logs in
6. `Session.lastAttemptedAction` is performed/cleared

If nothing is stored in the `lastAttemptedAction`, then nothing will be ran. The user will silently login, and continue on his or her merry way.